# How can I select JavaScript "Id" by var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

All I want is set getElementById by var (it must be automatic because I have got multiple of this range inputs (brightness, contrast, sharpen, etc.). 
How can I do this?

```js
    function showVal(value, id) {
      var spanId = "#" + id + "Id";
      document.getElementById("\"" + spanId + "\"").innerHTML = value;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row" style="display: inline-block; width: 45%; margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;">
  <div class="col-sm-5" style="padding: 2px;">
    <label class="control-label" style="float: left">Jasność:</label>
    <span class="filterValue" id="brightnessId">0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-7" style="padding: 2px;">
    <input id="brightness" type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="1" value="0" data-filter="brightness" onchange="showVal(this.value, this.id)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you passing `#` and quotes as an ID?

Comment: my mistake! I'm mixing jQ with JS... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `#`, and don't need to enclose it between `""`

```
   function showVal(value, id) {
        var spanId = id + "Id";
        document.getElementById(spanId).innerHTML = value;
   }
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/090r3d3z/)

You also could write this code like this:

```
function showVal(obj) {
        var spanId = obj.id + "Id";
        document.getElementById(spanId).innerHTML = obj.value;
}
```

and use only `this` in your HTML

```
<input id="brightness" type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="1" value="0" data-filter="brightness" onchange="showVal(this)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing up jQuery and vanilla JavaScript . . . you should simply be able to use this:

```
function showVal(value, id) {
    document.getElementById(id + "Id").innerHTML = value;
}
```

Comment: thank you! It works perfectly and this example is the shortest!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have included `jQuery` in tags, I'd use it. I'd also use `mousemove` instead of `change`, so that your output element gets updated at real time:

input field:

```
<input id="brightness" type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="1" value="0" data-filter="brightness">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#brightness').mousemove(function(){
   $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'Id').text($(this).val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tt4afaom/)

---

**OR**, Because your input field have `data-filter="..."` attribute and you want to have more fields which practically perform the same function (contrast, sharpness, etc...), I'd remove `id`, add `class` as selector and then use this `data-filter` attribute to match output element (`span`). So that is the whole process simple and automated:

```
<input class="settings" type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="1" value="0" data-filter="#brightness">
<input class="settings" type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="1" value="0" data-filter="#contrast">
<input class="settings" type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="1" value="0" data-filter="#sharpness">
```

jQuery (for all these fields):

```
$('.settings').mousemove(function(){
   $($(this).data('filter')).text($(this).val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/38rr6w1g/)